# Python: Plot a sparse matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a sparse matrix X, shape (6000, 300). I'd like something like a scatterplot which has a dot where the X(i, j) != 0, and blank space otherwise. I don't know how many nonzero entries there are in each row of X. X[0] has 15 nonzero entries, X[1] has 3, etc. The maximum number of nonzero entries in a row is 16.

Attempts:

- `plt.imshow(X)` results in a tall, skinny graph because of the shape of X. Using `plt.imshow(X, aspect='auto)` will stretch out the graph horizontally, but the dots get stretched out to become ellipses, and the plot becomes hard to read.
- `ax.spy` suffers from the same problem.
- `bokeh` seems promising, but really taxes my jupyter kernel.

Bonus:

- The nonzero entries of X are positive real numbers. If there was some way to reflect their magnitude, that would be great as well (e.g. colour intensity, transparency, or across a colour bar).
- Every 500 rows of X belong to the same class. That's 12 classes * 500 observations (rows) per class = 6000 rows. E.g. X[:500] are from class A, X[500:1000] are from class B, etc. Would be nice to colour-code the dots by class. For the moment I'll settle for manually including horizontal lines every 500 rows to delineate between classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nonzero()` to find the non zero elements and use `scatter()` plot the points:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(6000, 300)
a[a < 0.9999] = 0
r, c = np.nonzero(a)
pl.scatter(r, c, c=a[r, c])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me heatmap is the best candidate for this type of plot. imshow() will return u a colored matrix with color scale legend.

I don't get ur stretched ellipses problem, shouldnt it be a colored squred for each data point?

u can try log color scale if it is sparse. also plot the 12 classes separately to analyze if theres any inter-class differences.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.matshow` also turned out to be a feasible solution. I could also plot a heatmap with colorbars and all that.